# How to update attribute of child model in parent show page? Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, undefined

Getting error: `undefined method 'dueler'`.

A `duel` has_many `duelers`.

```
Dueler.last
 id: 20,
 user_id: 78,
 challenge_id: 178,
 duel_id: 13,
 accept: nil>
```

How can a dueler `:accept` the duel in **duels/show.html.erb**?

```
<% @duel.duelers.each do |dueler| %>
  <%= dueler.user.name %> <%= dueler.user.last_name %> will <%= dueler.challenge.name %><br>
  <% if current_user.id == dueler.user_id %>
    # undefined method 'dueler' for #<Duel:0x007ffd32ae2400>
    <%= form_for(@duel.dueler) do |f| %> 
        <%= f.check_box :accept %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
The loser(s) will <%= @duel.consequence %><br>
If everyone succeeds they will <%= @duel.reward %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you will need to use fields_for tag
Check this out: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are making things complex your self**
be clear about models and relationship you have and columns you need to update then edit your question. Then I can help.